# Which one is faster in MySQL, update whole table or update with WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I have simple question. There are similar questions to this. But none of them satisfied me.

Queries:

```
UPDATE products SET indexed = 1;
```

and

```
UPDATE products SET indexed = 1 WHERE indexed = 0;
```

Which one of the given queries will be faster?

Numer of rows in table can be between 1M and 2M. And number of rows with `indexed = 0` can be maximum 1K rows.

Comment: It depends.  Is there an index on the "indexed" column?  What is the ratio of rows with indexed == 1 to other possible values?   (A useless update probably costs more than a test ...)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213397/is-it-worth-checking-value-with-select-before-updating/213400#213400 make sure to read all answers.

Comment: @StephenC, Why would I index an `integer` column?

Comment: To improve query / update performance.  Possibly.  Depending on the use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster would be `UPDATE products SET indexed = 1 WHERE indexed = 0;` as it would only look and update on lines where index is 0

Edit: also check what @EzLo suggested!